# Linux tail write error and tail write error connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting; it would be great if I can get some help with the question below.

I have a bash script which has the following lines inside a `for` loop

```
f=`head -$m "$x" | tail -$gg | egrep -m 20 -A 3 "SYSTEM ERROR|ER-0FFF" | awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" ";} {print}'`
```

where,
`$x` is a pathname of a file 
`$m` the start line of interest in the file 
`$gg` the end line of interest in the same file

It sporadically produces two types of errors:

```
tail: write error
```

or

```
tail: write error: Connection reset by peer
```

So what am I trying to achieve here?

I have 1000s of event logs stored in some directory/sub-directories. I currently have information on the pathname of the event logs that are of interest to me. Further I also have information on the start and end lines of the parts in that log file that I am interested in, so, with the above command I first extract that part of interest using head and tail and then start pattern-matching and extracting the 3 lines after each of the patterns that were found, then I print it in the variable.
**Note**: It is important that all the lines that are extracted, are concatenated in one single line, bcos with the contents of this variable will be appended to the last field of a specific line in another file, hence the awk in the above command

any ideas guys on how to fix this

Comment: Your `head -$m "$x"` is producing insufficient output for `tail` command causing this error. What are you trying to achieve here? Am sure there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Hi Inian, I have added additional info to the question

Comment: You can do that in a single awk command? Can you post a minimal input and expected output from your big list for us to try?

Comment: I will try to add this soon

Comment: Eh, that's a *lot* of fork'ing and exec' ing to be placed inside a for loop. If your for loop fails to terminate you can say goodbye to your machine.